# Making a synchronous loop from synchronous callbacks with node.js + Q deferred/promises module

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, q

The popular JavaScript module [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) implements the deferred / promise / futures concept. I think it's mainly used with node.js but it support browser use as well. I'm using it with node.js.

To do sequential calls you chain one promise to the next using `then()` but in a loop it can be so counterintuitive than I'm finding it difficult to do the same as this pseudocode:

```
forever {
    l = getline();

    if (l === undefined) {
        break;
    } else {
        doStuff(l);
    }
}
```

The Q documentation includes an example which seems pretty similar:

```
var funcs = [foo, bar, baz, qux];

var result = Q.resolve(initialVal);
funcs.forEach(function (f) {
    result = result.then(f);
});
return result;
```

But in trying many ways to adapt this example to my problem I'm having no success at all.

Unlike in the example code I'm not iterating over an array but wish to loop until an end condition is met. Also I always call the same function. My function does not take the previous result as a parameter to the next call. Each call takes no arguments but the return value decides whether to continue the loop.

These seemingly trivial differences are causing some kind of insurmountable mental block. Now I can see why many people have trouble understanding promises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that if you return a promise from a `then` callback, then it will replace the existing promise. The idea is that after executing one iteration of whatever chain of things you want to do in the loop body, you either return a value, which will resolve the promise, or you return a new promise that will execute the body of the loop again.

```
function iterateUntil(endValue){
  // This line would eventually resolve the promise with something matching
  // the final ending condition.
  return Q.resolve('some value')
    .then(function(value){
      // If the promise was resolved with the loop end condition then you just
      // return the value or something, which will resolve the promise.
      if (value == endValue) return value;

      // Otherwise you call 'iterateUntil' again which will replace the current
      // promise with a new one that will do another iteration.
      else return iterateUntil(endValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: I did try and fail to get a recursive version working as well as an iterative one. I'll try this but isn't there a risk of blowing up the stack? My project will be processing text files with many millions of lines.

Comment: @hippietrail This recursive solution should work. This won't kill the stack because the stack starts fresh for async operations, so the `then` callback is the start of a whole new stack starting at the next process tick.

Comment: This seems to be working but I can't find a way to trap an end condition. By that I mean I want some code to execute only after this loop completes. In fact I'm pretty sure it's not even ending due to the line `if (value == endValue) return value;` because if I print it my endValue never shows up. Adding errbacks in various places never result in any being called either. And the worst part is that Q seems to suppress any stack trace - when it fails it always fails silently.

Comment: Can you add your attempt to the question? Its tough to give good suggestions with just the description.

Comment: You answer did make it easier for me to handle some other asynchronous looping problems with Q so I'm accepting it. I'll play with this specific problem some more and post detailed code if I still can't crack it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this with the following code and node froze at 67000 left out of 1,000,000 eating 100% of a cpu.  I think it is safe for small to Large sized loops but huge loops are a bad idea.  http://nopaste.dk/p53932

Comment: @Chas.Owens Interesting, yeah I'd have to do some profiling to see what is taking up all that memory.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to Q: [Synchronous for loop](https://gist.github.com/steve-taylor/5075717).

Comment: I was using these kinds of loops too, but once you get a few nested ones, especially with different flavours of loops, you can end up with a new kind of unreadable spaghetti code. I often confused myself and decided that in this case hand-coding without some kind of more readable abstraction was the way to go. For single non-nested loops in small scripts though I agree with you.